# Repair boot loader when trying to install win 8 as dual boot alongside win 7

Tags: boot

I wasn't ready to commit to win 8 fully on my work box. I have attempted installing it in its own partition. When it was installing from iso loaded from a file on the ein7 partition, upon reboot, it's come up with a 'issing operating system' error.

Booting from a USB from the iso, using bcdedit, without any parameters, it says it cannot find anything.

Auto repair from the bootable USB said it couldn't find any problems it could solve.

Anyone have any thoughts? Trying to avoid a complete wipe and install.

I know the win7/c: drive is encrypted and requires a pw key to boot. Is that the problem? Can't seem to find anything that fits my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reach any windows OS? if so try [creating a windows repair](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-system-repair-disc) disk, insert it, should fix the problem

another solution which might work is [boot repair disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/), just download it, burn it, boot it and it should repair the boot menu automatically